# Will my heroku app be affected by adminium shutdown?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, shutdown, add-on, dyno

I got a shutdown notice about adminium, but I can't tell if my app is even using adminium. It's there, but I think it might be a remnant from when I first set the app up 6 years ago. Since, I've had to upgrade the stack twice, and then when salesforce bought Heroku and deleted my database without warning, I spent weeks figuring out how to get it back and re-attach it.
[image: Resources dashboard]

When I try to look into adminium on my account, it looks like it's not even connected to anything. I don't really understand what adminium is, so I'm hoping the shutdown won't affect my app. This is the account settings page when I click on adminium in the table in the pic. The app is currently working just fine, so this database error doesn't seem to effect anything, which would indicate adminium isn't currently doing anything.
[image: adminium account settings]

One thing I know for certain, if it does affect me, it'll take 3-6 weeks for me to pry any helpful information out of tech support. Thank you in advance for any assistance. Please let me know if I need to include more/different information. I made this app for my dad and every 12-18 months, heroku does something that breaks it and I spend a month trying to fix it.

Comment: How can we possibly answer this? We have no idea what your application does, or what services it requires.

Answer (score 0):

No, Adminium is just an add-on for Heroku that connects to your database and allows you to browse the data with a GUI.

You can ignore this.